# Unix SED - get title then set it another place

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a HTML file like this:

```
<html><head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Title of this page: PAGE_TITLE
</body>
</html>
```

How can replace PAGE_TITLE on title?

I try this command:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*?<title>\)\(.*?\)\(<\/title>.*?\)PAGE_TITLE/\1\2\3\2/' page.html
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you required to use `sed`? `awk` would be an easier tool for this.

Comment: Can you show how do it with awk?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/<title>/ { title = $0; sub(".*<title>", "", title); sub("</title>.*", "", title)}
     /PAGE_TITLE/ { sub("PAGE_TITLE", title); }
     1' filename > filename.new
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex to parse HTML. Using a proper parser & [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
# fetch title string
title=$(xml sel -t -v /html/head/title file.html)
# edit file in-place
xml ed -L -u '/html/body/text()' -v "Title of this page: $title" file.html
```

`xml` is [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

Check: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: first query the title: `title=$(xml sel -t -v /html/head/title file.html)` and then use that value in the edit command

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `sed` script is that you are using `*?` which is an unsupported regex extension. You can get much the same result with `[^<>]*` instead of `.*?`.

Also, the `<title>` element is not allowed inside the HTML `<body>` so you should not include it; you are creating invalid HTML.